# Generating functions with macros in C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, macros

I have the following macro that is intended to generate functions in the current scope or namespace:

```
#define MAKE_FUNC(FNAME) \
template <typename T> \
T ##FNAME## (const T& t) \
{\
   return t; \
}

MAKE_FUNC(foo)
MAKE_FUNC(boo)

int main()
{
   foo(1);
   boo(2);
}
```

The following is the error message when compiling the above code:

```
prog.cpp:8:1: error: pasting "Tfoo" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
prog.cpp:9:1: error: pasting "Tboo" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
prog.cpp:8: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Tfoo’ with no type
prog.cpp:9: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Tboo’ with no type
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:13: error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope
prog.cpp:14: error: ‘boo’ was not declared in this scope
```

http://ideone.com/paiu1

It seems like the concatenation has fail, is there anyway around this problem?

Comment: The concatenation didn't fail. It worked exactly as advertised. It appears that you didn't want the concatenation though.

Comment: I know that I'm supposed to be all I'm-OK-you're-OK, but *macros suck most of the time*.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: very true. :)

Comment: In addition to not wanting to concatinate, trying to concatinate anything and a '(' creates an "invalid token" on some compilers.  Some compilers gobble it right up.  Not really having ever motivated myself to become an expert on the preprocessor...I don't know which is right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want

```
T FNAME (const T& t) \
```

`##` concatenates, you don't want to concatenate.